# Extract all text under an h2 tag using scrapy

Tags: python, html, web, scrapy, screen-scraping

I need to search for an h2 tag with certain value and extract all text following it until the next h2 tag or end of page. so if the page is

```
<h1 id="DDPSupport-InternalResources"><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"><strong>Internal Resources</strong></span></h1>
<h2 id="DDPSupport-GeneralInformation">General Information</h2>
<ul><li><a href="/display/ladtechtme/DDP+overview">DDP overview</a></li>
<li><a href="/display/ladtechtme/DDP+Configuration+guide">DDP Config guide</a></li>
<li><a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1338281922">Custom DPR</a></li>
<li><a href="/display/ladtechtme/Build+custom+package">Build custom package</a></li>
<li><a href="/display/ladtechtme/Unit+testing">Unit testing</a></li>
<li><a href="/display/ladtechtme/FAQ">FAQ </a></li>
<li><a href="/display/ladtechtme/Misc+BKMs">Misc BKMs</a></li></ul>
<h2 id="DDPSupport-UseCases">Use Cases</h2>
<ul><li><a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1338281922">Custom DPR </a></li>...
```

, the expected output is

```
DDP overview
DDP Config guide
Custom DPR
Build custom package
Unit testing
FAQ
Misc BKMs
```

I am using the following code:

```
for head in response.xpath("//div[@class='wiki-content']/h2"):
   sub=str(head.xpath("text()").extract())
   sub = sub.replace("[","")
   sub = sub.replace("'","")
   sub = sub.replace("]","")
   if sub == 'General Information':
        lines = head.xpath("//following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2)=1]//text()").extract()
        print(str(lines))
```

I am getting some result but not the desired one.
My output consists of the text of the next h2 tag.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you are using `//` instead of `.//` for `head.xpath()`, which is probably unintended, and the reason you are getting unexpected results.

Comment: @Gallaecio Thanks. I checked it. It still doesn't give the desired result. Giving the same result as before.

Comment: I even tried ```.//following-sibling::*[count(following-sibling::h2[text()=sub_next])]//text()``` where sub_next is 'Use Cases' just to try something different. Still its the same

Comment: What about `.//following-sibling::ul[1]//text()`?